# SVG: несколько эффектов в одном фильтре

Tags: css, svg, svg-filter

Я пытаюсь реализовать несколько теней в одном фильтре SVG, но я считаю, что мой вопрос более общий, чем этот, а именно, - **как добавить несколько эффектов в один фильтр SVG?** В моем случае это именно то, что я пытаюсь сделать.

У меня есть документ SVG, который в настоящее время содержит единственный элемент пути, и я применил единственный эффект тени к этому элементу пути.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1440" height="1750">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.2"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset dx="12" dy="12" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
      <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"></feFlood>
      <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"></feComposite>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <path xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z z" fill="#2DA9D6" filter="url(#dropshadow)"></path>
</svg>
```

Это дает мне SVG, который выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я хочу добавить вторую (совершенно другую) тень к этому же элементу пути. Например, скажем, тень, которая идет вверх и слева от элемента. В CSS вся моя тень может выглядеть так:

`box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -5px -5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Как я могу сделать эти множественные тени с помощью фильтров SVG? Я рассмотрел [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338380/multiple-filters-for-single-object-in-svg), в котором предлагается поместить несколько эффектов в один фильтр, но я не уверен, как объединить несколько эффектов в один фильтр.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG: Multiple Effects in One Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22756224/7394871) от участника  [@Nick Budden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740836/nick-budden).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/22756224/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать атрибуты `result`, чтобы дать имя выходным данным примитивного элемента фильтра, считая его своего рода атрибутом локального идентификатора фильтра. Затем вы можете использовать это имя в качестве входных данных фильтра с атрибутами `in` или `in2`.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1440" height="1750">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow">
     <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/> 
      <feOffset dx="12" dy="12" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feOffset dx="-20" dy="-12" result="offsetblur2" in="blur"/>
      <feComponentTransfer result="shadow1" in="offsetblur">
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feComponentTransfer result="shadow2" in="offsetblur2">
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode in="shadow1"/>
        <feMergeNode in="shadow2"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <path xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z z" fill="#2DA9D6" filter="url(#dropshadow)"></path>
</svg>
```

Смотрите [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGUM2/)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22757585/7394871) от участника  [@Erik Dahlström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109374/erik-dahlstr%c3%b6m).</sub>